# Wrap a tag around plain html text

Tags: java, regex, jsoup, text-parsing, tag-soup

I have this structure in my html document:

```
<p>
"<em>You</em> began the evening well, Charlotte," said Mrs.&nbsp;Bennet with civil          self–command to Miss Lucas. "<em>You</em> were Mr.&nbsp;Bingley's first choice."
</p>
```

But i need my "plain text" to be wrappted in tags, to be able to process it :)

```
<p>
    <text>"</text>
    <em>You</em>
    <text> began the evening well, Charlotte," said Mrs.&nbsp;Bennet with civil self–command to Miss Lucas. "</text>
    <em>You</em>
    <text> were Mr.&nbsp;Bingley's first choice."</text>
</p>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I've looked at tagsoup and jsoup but i dont seem a way to solve this easily. Maybe using some fancy regexp.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

```
public static Node toTextElement(String str) {
    Element e = new Element(Tag.valueOf("text"), "");
    e.appendText(str);
    return e;
}

public static void replaceTextNodes(Node root) {
    if (root instanceof TextNode)
        root.replaceWith(toTextElement(((TextNode) root).text()));
    else
        for (Node child : root.childNodes())
            replaceTextNodes(child);
}
```

Test code:

```
String html = "<p>\"<em>You</em> began the evening well, Charlotte,\" " +
         "said Mrs.&nbsp;Bennet with civil self–command to Miss Lucas." +
         " \"<em>You</em> were Mr.&nbsp;Bingley's first choice.\"</p>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for (Node n : doc.body().children())
    replaceTextNodes(n);

System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>
   <text>
    &quot;
   </text><em>
    <text>
     You
    </text></em>
   <text>
     began the evening well, Charlotte,&quot; said Mrs.&nbsp;Bennet with civil self–command to Miss Lucas. &quot;
   </text><em>
    <text>
     You
    </text></em>
   <text>
     were Mr.&nbsp;Bingley's first choice.&quot;
   </text></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Im actually trying to use this to render html on a canvas using paint and draw text methods. Is this a good way to start? :)